# Time complexity of operations on Order Statistics Tree and 1D points problem

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, data-structures, tree

I ran into the following interview question:

> We need a data structure to keep *n* points on the X-axis such that we get efficient implementations of
> `Insert(x)`, `Delete(x)` and `Find (a, b)` (giving the **number** of points in
> the interval `[a, b]`). Assume that the maximum number returned by `Find(a, b)` is `k`.
>
> 1. We can create a data structure that performs the three operations in *O(log n)*
> 2. We can create a data structure that performs `Insert` and `Delete` in *O(log n)* and `Find` in *O(k + log n)*.

I know from general information that `Find` is like a Range on 1D points (but for counting elements in this question, i.e we need the number of elements). If we use for example an AVL tree, then we get the time complexities of option (2).

But I was surprised when told that (1) is the correct answer. Why is (1) the right answer?

Comment: if `k=n` then  `O(k + log n) = O(n)`

Comment: The data structure is an order statistic tree, and the log time implementation of operations like `find` is exactly what it's *for*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree

Comment: Any kind of search tree, with each node also recording some cumulative statistic over all of its children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is indeed (1).

The idea of an AVL tree is fine, and your conclusions are right. But you can extend the AVL tree such that each node has one extra property: the number of values that precede the node's own value. You would have to take care in the AVL operations (including rotations) that this extra property is kept up to date. But this can be done with a constant overhead, so it does not impact the time complexities of `Insert` or `Delete`.

Then `Find` could just search the node with value *a* (or the one with the greatest value less than *a*), and do the same for value *b*. From both nodes that you find you get the extra property. The subtraction of these two will give the required result. There are some boundary cases to take into consideration, like when *a* is present in the tree, then that node itself should be counted too, otherwise not. It may be that no node is found with a value less than or equal to *a*. Then the missing property should be taken as a 0 in the subtraction.

Clearly this makes `Find` independent of its return value (up to *k*). The two binary searches give it a time complexity of *O(logn)*.

Comment: One for locating value *a*  and another for locating value *b*. The way to find a value in a binary search tree (such as AVL) is *binary search*, which has a time complexity of *O(logn)*.

Comment: Yes, it is like that.